# No Java Swing, devo estender JPanel e top-level containers como JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

Tem no [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5895282/2241463) mas não me dei por satisfeito com as respostas, e temporariamente não estou podendo perguntar na [SE.SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/).

Containers top-level como o `JFrame` acho que não há necessidade, mas um `JPanel` meio que foi feito para ser uma coisa abstrata, e portanto talvez extensível.

Devo estendê-lo? A regra diz que só quando vai estender (sobrescrever) algum método ou (talvez) estender sua funcionalidade, e tem que respeitar Liskov.

Um JPanel com um conjunto de botões (um painel de botões) merece ser estendido? Um com entidades de negócio (tem um nome pra elas, UI model ou algo assim) merece ser estendido? Com métodos de negócio?

Não fica engessado depois?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Prefira usar composição ao invés de herança se possível. Dessa forma, você poderia criar classes que contenham diversos campos dos tipos `JPanel`, `JButton`, `JRadioButton`, etc. e utilizá-los.

Se quiser ir pela herança mesmo, o `JPanel` é uma classe relativamente limpa e fácil de se herdar, dificilmente isso te causará problemas. Mas embora você possa extender `JPanel` facilmente, a própria `JPanel` acaba sendo uma classe um tanto inócua porque ela é uma subclasse praticamente vazia. Nesse caso, valeria mais a pena herdar de `JComponent`, que é a superclasse de `JPanel`.